# User Data is not inserting into mongodb using Node API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am creating a Restful API on Node.js and storing data into Mongodb. and working on user registration API.

**app.js**

```
apiRoutes.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.name || !req.body.password) {
     res.json({success: false, msg: 'Please pass Name and Password.'});
     } else {
          var newUser = new User({
            name:req.body.name, 
            password:req.body.password
          });
          console.log(req.body.name);
    // save the user
      newUser.save(function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
             return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Username already exists.'});
            }else{
            console.log(data);
            res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user.'});}
          });
       }
    });
```

Consuming API using Angular.js

```
 //factory for user register
 app.factory('RegistrationFactory',  function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/signup/:id',{id:'@_id'},{update:{method:'PUT'}});
 });

 //controller for registration
app.controller('registerCtrl', function($scope, RegistrationFactory, $location){
 $scope.regUser=new RegistrationFactory();
 $scope.register=function(){
        console.log($scope.newUser);
        $scope.regUser.$save(function(){
                            console.log("User Registerd");
                            });

        } ;

})
```

**register.html**

```
<div class="post" ng-controller="registerCtrl">
        <form  method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="newUser.name" />
        </div>   
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" ng-model="newUser.password"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="register()">Register</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

So, My problem is that, this API is working fine on `POSTMAN` but its not working on  my HTML form. Please review my code. Whenever I click on Register button its seems like that on button click API is not hitting. nothing is happening.
Please review my code and suggest me solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your `register` function is calling? at angular side

Comment: Yes , its calling.

Comment: So you are stuck on back-end side?are you getting any response after clicking `register`?

Comment: No.. No response from back end. But when I hit my api in `POSTMAN` then its working good.

Comment: provide an example of the `User` class definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from angular controller you are not passing the `newUser` object to `$resource` or `regUser` change the controller code to below

```
 //controller for registration
app.controller('registerCtrl', function($scope, RegistrationFactory, $location){
$scope.register=function(){
    console.log($scope.newUser);
    $scope.regUser=new RegistrationFactory($scope.newUser);
    $scope.regUser.$save(function(){
                        console.log("User Registerd");
                        });

    } ;

})
```

Comment: Yeah.... your right.. Now its working fine. But in `postman` its working without passing the object to `$resource`

Comment: in postman or angular you need to input specify data that needs at server side. in postman you feed it to form data and send to server. in angular you need to specify data like how i showed you or you can use `ng-submit`.